# Python + OpenCV - Show Video Feed from other script on Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have written a Python Script with the sole intention of detecting text on the webcam video feed using cv2 and pytesseract.

This function is called webcamOCR, and it's in `OCRDetection.py`.

For `gui.py` I have designed the following mockup:

[image: Mockup for GUI]

When I try to call webcamOCR from `OCRDetection.py` all it does is to open the webcam feed in a separate window.

How can I make it to display the Video Feed just like I designed it? Any pointers would be great.

This is the code I've written so far:

OCRDetection.py:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import pytesseract
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression

##Route to pytesseract on MacOS.
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.1.0/bin/tesseract'

def box_extractor(scores, geometry, min_confidence):

    num_rows, num_cols = scores.shape[2:4]
    rectangles = []
    confidences = []

    for y in range(num_rows):
        scores_data = scores[0, 0, y]
        x_data0 = geometry[0, 0, y]
        x_data1 = geometry[0, 1, y]
        x_data2 = geometry[0, 2, y]
        x_data3 = geometry[0, 3, y]
        angles_data = geometry[0, 4, y]

        for x in range(num_cols):
            if scores_data[x] < min_confidence:
                continue

            offset_x, offset_y = x * 4.0, y * 4.0

            angle = angles_data[x]
            cos = np.cos(angle)
            sin = np.sin(angle)

            box_h = x_data0[x] + x_data2[x]
            box_w = x_data1[x] + x_data3[x]

            end_x = int(offset_x + (cos * x_data1[x]) + (sin * x_data2[x]))
            end_y = int(offset_y + (cos * x_data2[x]) - (sin * x_data1[x]))
            start_x = int(end_x - box_w)
            start_y = int(end_y - box_h)

            rectangles.append((start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y))
            confidences.append(scores_data[x])

    return rectangles, confidences


def get_arguments():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-v', '--video', type=str,
                    help='path to optional video file')
    ap.add_argument('-east', '--east', type=str, required=True,
                    help='path to EAST text detection model')
    ap.add_argument('-c', '--min_confidence', type=float, default=0.5,
                    help='minimum confidence to process a region')
    ap.add_argument('-w', '--width', type=int, default=320,
                    help='resized image width (multiple of 32)')
    ap.add_argument('-e', '--height', type=int, default=320,
                    help='resized image height (multiple of 32)')
    ap.add_argument('-p', '--padding', type=float, default=0.0,
                    help='padding on each ROI border')
    arguments = vars(ap.parse_args())

    return arguments


def webcamOCR():

    args = get_arguments()

    w, h = None, None
    new_w, new_h = args['width'], args['height']
    ratio_w, ratio_h = None, None

    layer_names = ['feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid', 'feature_fusion/concat_3']

    print("Starting the OCR Engine...")
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args["east"])

    if not args.get('video', False):
        print("Activating webcam...")
        vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Waiting to detect text...")
    else:
        vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args['video'])

    fps = FPS().start()

    while True:
        frame = vs.read()
        frame = frame[1] if args.get('video', False) else frame
        

        if frame is None:
            break

        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1000)
        orig = frame.copy()
        orig_h, orig_w = orig.shape[:2]

        if w is None or h is None:
            h, w = frame.shape[:2]
            ratio_w = w / float(new_w)
            ratio_h = h / float(new_h)

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (new_w, new_h))

        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (new_w, new_h), (123.68, 116.78, 103.94),
                                     swapRB=True, crop=False)
        net.setInput(blob)
        scores, geometry = net.forward(layer_names)

        rectangles, confidences = box_extractor(scores, geometry, min_confidence=args['min_confidence'])
        boxes = non_max_suppression(np.array(rectangles), probs=confidences)

        for (start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) in boxes:

            start_x = int(start_x * ratio_w)
            start_y = int(start_y * ratio_h)
            end_x = int(end_x * ratio_w)
            end_y = int(end_y * ratio_h)

            dx = int((end_x - start_x) * args['padding'])
            dy = int((end_y - start_y) * args['padding'])

            start_x = max(0, start_x - dx)
            start_y = max(0, start_y - dy)
            end_x = min(orig_w, end_x + (dx * 2))
            end_y = min(orig_h, end_y + (dy * 2))

            ocRegion = orig[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x]

            # recognizing text
            config = '-l eng --oem 1 --psm 6'
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(ocRegion, config=config)

            if text != "":
                if len(text)==8: 
                    print(f"Detected text: {text}")
                    cv2.rectangle(orig, (start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    cv2.putText(orig, text, (start_x, start_y - 20),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.2, (34, 226, 66), 3)
                break
            break            

        fps.update()

        cv2.imshow("Real-Time OCR", orig)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if key == ord('q'):
            break

    fps.stop()
    print(f"[INFO] elapsed time {round(fps.elapsed(), 2)}")
    print(f"[INFO] approx. FPS : {round(fps.fps(), 2)}")

    if not args.get('video', False):
        vs.stop()

    else:
        vs.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is gui.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2
import imutils

from OCRDetection import *        

def Exit():
    window.destroy()
    

def Start():
    global cap
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    webcamFeed()

def Stop():
    lblVideo.image = ""
    lblEmpty.configure(text="")
    cap.release()

def webcamFeed():
    webcamOCR()

def Exit():
    global cap
    cap.release()

cap = None
window = Tk()
window.title("Real Time OCR")
formTitle = Label(window, text="Real Time OCR",font=("Arial",24))
formTitle.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1)

btn = Button(window,text="Start",font=("Arial",12),background="gray",fg="white", command=Start)
btn2 = Button(window,text="Detener",font=("Arial",12),background="orange",fg="white", command=Stop)
btn3 = Button(window,text="Exit",font=("Arial",12),background="red",fg="white",command=Exit)
lblVideo = Label(window)
lblVideo.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,pady=10)
btn.grid(column=0,row=2)
btn2.grid(column=1,row=2)
btn3.grid(column=2,row=2)
lblEmpty = Label(window,text="",width=20)
lblEmpty.grid(column=4,row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Note: In order to run `gui.py` I have to pass the arguments that `OCRDetection.py` requires.

Example: `python3 OCRDetection.py -east frozen_east_text_detection.pb"